# How to apply conditional navigation with a seamless transitions between destinations?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

By the requirements, our app content should be accessible only by authenticated users. According to Google guidelines regarding navigation, the app should have a [fixed start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) which is some "home" or "main" screen. The authentication from a navigation perspective is the case for [conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login). We understand the ideology of described navigation principles and agree with them.

The example for login described by Google works well for the user actions that should lead him to login at some point. But for our scenario, we need to navigate to the authentication screen right after the navigation graph is initialized and we have received the current state of the user session (which is represented as LiveData). Going back (canceling authentication) from the user perspective should look like leaving the app as for the user this should be the only screen in the "logical" navigation chain. That means such decisions of performing conditional navigation and exiting primary navigation graph on authentication cancellation are performed by the screen which is declared as start destination. Logically, applying such an approach does its work, but technically this leads to noticeable transitions between those screens. In both cases, when the authentication screen is opened by the start destination and canceling authentication the start destination screen is visible for the fractions of a second which is an unacceptable user experience. A video representation of this behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IijRRG_DeQE

The described implementation is made within a single activity. Screens are represented as fragments.

Is there any solution for such a scenario with seamless conditional navigation from your experience?

Comment: You can set the start destination programmatically if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Provide your graph and your desired path result would be better.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi: programmatic change of start destination breaks fixed start destination principle. In this case, you also will have a login screen as the root screen of the navigation graph.

Comment: @SamChen: This behavior could be reproduced just by a couple of elements in the graph: https://imgur.com/a/OAdommG